# Best way to build dynamic SQL involving an optional limit?

Tags: jooq

What is the best way to optionally apply a LIMIT to a query in JOOQ? I want to run:

```
SelectSeekStepN<Record> readyToFetch = dslContext.select(selectFields).
    from(derivedTable).
    where(conditions).
    orderBy(orderForward);
if (length != Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    readyToFetch = readyToFetch.limit(length);
```

`limit()` returns `SelectLimitPercentStep<Record>` which is not a sub-class of `SelectSeekStepN<Record>` so I get a compiler error.

If, on the other hand, I change the return type of `readyToFetch` from `SelectSeekStepN<Record>` to `Select<Record>` which is compatible with the return type of `limit()` then I cannot invoke `limit()` on `Select<Record>`. I would need to explicitly cast it to `SelectSeekStepN<Record>`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Maybe JOOQ should treat `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as a special value (no limit) to make this kind of code easier to write...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Offering a no-op to pass to clauses like `LIMIT`

There is an occasional feature request asking for such no-op clauses in the DSL API, which would obviously be very helpful, especially in the case of `LIMIT`, where there is currently no non-hacky workaround. Unfortunately, there's no good solution yet, other than the one you've already mentioned in your question, to dynamically construct your SQL query.

For most clauses where optionality is required, something like a [`DSL.noCondition()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#noCondition()) exists. A [`DSL.noTable()`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9635) has been requested, but not yet implemented (as of jOOQ 3.14). Same with a "no-op" for `LIMIT`: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11551

#### Getting the types right with dynamic SQL

Your own question already contains the solution. It's just a minor typing problem. You probably chose to assign your intermediary step to `SelectSeekStepN` because your IDE suggested this type. But you can use any super type, instead.

```java
Select<Record> readyToFetch;
SelectLimitStep<Record> readyToLimit;

readyToFetch = readyToLimit = dslContext.select(selectFields).
    from(derivedTable).
    where(conditions).
    orderBy(orderForward);
if (length != Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    readyToFetch = readyToLimit.limit(length);
readyToFetch.fetch();
```

You can take some inspiration by the [`ParserImpl`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/main/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/impl/ParserImpl.java) logic. It does this all over the place. Assignment expressions are a blessing!

Alternative using type inference on conditional expressions:

```java
SelectLimitStep<Record> limit = dslContext.select(selectFields).
    from(derivedTable).
    where(conditions).
    orderBy(orderForward);

Result<?> result = (length != Integer.MAX_VALUE ? limit.limit(length) : limit).fetch();
```

#### Using `null` as a way to explicitly indicate the absence of `LIMIT`

Using `null` as a way to indicate the absence of a `LIMIT` is a very bad idea for at least 3 reasons:

- Most jOOQ API interprets `(Field<?>) null` as a `NULL` bind value or `NULL` literal, never as an absent value. It would be very surprising if suddenly, we used `null` for that purpose only in `LIMIT`
- Even if we did, we'd have to start distinguishing between `null` (the internal interpretation of an absent value) and `null` (the value you as a user provide jOOQ with *explicitly*). So, we'd need some `noLimit()` object anyway internally, to make the distinction, in case of which, why not just expose that as API instead of letting you hack around?
- Some dialects support `NULL` limits. PostgreSQL interprets it an absent `LIMIT` (which I find very confusing, the `LIMIT` being "unknown"). Oracle interprets it as a `LIMIT 0`, which is much more reasonable. Other dialects (e.g. MySQL) reject `LIMIT NULL` as bad syntax, which is also reasonable. You're suggesting jOOQ overrides this behaviour and cleverly re-interprets it. I'd rather not!

Comment: For what it's worth, asking users to pass in a null `Number` instead of an `int` is a very reasonable solution in my opinion. All I was missing was a hint (a push in the right direction) from the Javadoc.

Comment: @Gili: Abusing `null` for this purpose is a very bad idea. In most jOOQ API, passing `(Field<?>) null` has the semantics of passing an explicit `null` bind variable or `null` SQL literal. Never an empty set or absent value. I'll expand my answer to illustrate why that would be a bad idea (as I already mentioned in the comment to your answer)

Comment: Cute approach (capturing the same result as two different types). Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I dug into the implementation and discovered that there is another method `limit(Number)` that treats `null` values as no limit. Consequently, the code could be written as:

```
Select<Record> readyToFetch = dslContext.select(selectFields).
    from(derivedTable).
    where(conditions).
    orderBy(orderForward).
    limit(length == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? null : length);
```

Comment: It's risky to rely on undocumented behaviour like this. After all, there might be a use-case (unlikely, but not 100% impossible) of wanting to pass a `null` bind variable to `LIMIT` for some reason, in case of which this would produce no results rather than all results.

Comment: @LukasEder Agreed. Are you able to provide an official (per the specification) escape hatch for this situation?

Comment: You already documented the official approach in your question :) It's not a bad approach at all. Just get the types right...